# Summernote Editor Content Not Displaying Properly on the Front End

Tags: php, html, css, summernote

When I insert a text or image content in Summernote editor, I can see the result.
However, on the front end, the HTML and CSS tags are not applied correctly.

I inspected the content on the browser and I can see that some characters are added.
So, those characters prevent the HTML and CSS code to apply.

For example, when I insert an image through the image functionality and put the URL, I get this link:

```
https://cliquedigitale.com4muz.com/%22/assets/img/blog/blog-page-big2.webp/%22
```

The `%22` is displayed as follows: `"`.

And when I inspect the image, I get:

```
<img src="\&quot;/assets/img/blog/blog-page-big2.webp\&quot;" style="\&quot;width:" 1052px;\"="">
```

`&quot;` is displayed as follows: `"`.

So, as you can see it keeps adding some characters.

Then, is it a CSS issue. I mean is my CSS code conflicting with Summernote CSS?

Or is it a PHP related problem?